# How to check the set to be closed?

Tags: real-analysis

The set is obtained by removing the rational points from the interval $[4,7].$ How do I check to see if this set is closed in $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: It's not. There is a sequence tending to $7$ through the irrationals, but 7 is not in the set.

Comment: you mean 7 is a limit point of the set?

Comment: Yes. I do. (Still haven't beaten the character limit.)

Comment: every point in [4,7] is the limit point of the required set?

Comment: Is *a* limit point - there is no *the* limit point of that set. Indeed, every point  in $[4, 7]$ is a limit point of that set. However, that's much more than you need. You can get away with showing that just one rational in $[4, 7]$ is a limit point of the irrationals in $[4, 7]$.

Comment: 4 is a rational point and thus 4 does not belong to the my required set. I am thinking that 4 is a limit point of the new set. Is my think is right?

Comment: Yes it is. Charactercharacter.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens thanks

Comment: @PatrickStevens To beat the character limit you can just add a bunch of \$

Comment: @PatrickStevens People often add `${{{{{}}}}}$` at the end of short replies.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Communicating this will help your understanding as well as the quality of replies.

Answer (score 10):

Take , $A=[4,7]\cap \mathbb I$ ; where , $\mathbb I$ is the set of all irrational points.

Then , $\bar A=[4,7]\not= A$.

So ..............?

Comment: i think that, A is dense in [4,7]. Is my think is correct?

Comment: Dense in **what ?**

Comment: @Avinash: Yes: both $A$ and $[4,7]\setminus A$ are dense in $[4,7]$.

Comment: @  Avinash N) Do you know the definition of ' Dense ' ? Here $A$ is NOT dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: yes i know. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using the theorem closed iff contains all limit points as in [Panja's Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416209/10549), it is instructive to appeal to the definition of closed as a set whose complement is open.

$$A^\sim = (-\infty,\,4) \cup (7,\,\infty) \cup ([4,\,7]\cap\mathbb{Q})$$

Consider $5\in A^\sim$. Any neighbourhood of $5$ contains an open interval of the form $(5-\epsilon_-,\,5+\epsilon_+)$ (with $1>\epsilon_+,\,\epsilon_->0$), which in turn contains $[5-\epsilon_-/2,\,5+\epsilon_+/2]$ which in turn contains irrationals not in $A^\sim$. So, no neighborhood of $5$ is contained in $A^\sim$.

Now use theorem open iff a neighborhood of all its points. Thus $A^\sim$ is not open, so its complement $A$ is not closed.